# PostgreSQL says "return and sql tuple descriptions are incompatible"

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot, pivot-table

I have the following data:

```
ID  CLASS   VALUE
1   NHB    700905.7243
1   HBW    164216.1311
1   HBO    700905.7243
2   NHB    146023.3792
2   HBW    89543.2972
2   HBO    82152.072
3   NHB    1409818.328
3   HBW    220430.7922
3   HBO    323512.9391
4   NHB    48711.3814
4   HBW    163385.1575
4   HBO    363352.3441
```

I want to reorganize it into the following:

```
ID     HBO             HBW              NHB
1   700905.7243    164216.1311      700905.7243
2   82152.072      89543.2972       146023.3792
3   323512.9391    220430.7922      1409818.328
4   363352.3441    163385.1575      48711.3814
```

Please note that the values in columns HBW, HBO and NHB are totals (sum).

Here is the script I am using to create the output:

```sql
-- CREATE EXTENSION tablefunc;

SELECT *
FROM  CROSSTAB
(
    'SELECT _tlfd.id,   
    _tlfd."class",
    _tlfd."value"
    FROM public._tlfd
    WHERE _tlfd."class" = ''HBW'' or _tlfd."class" = ''HBO'' or _tlfd."class" = ''NHB'' 
    ORDER BY 1,2'
) 
    AS
(
    "class" int, 
    "HBW" text,
    "HBO" text,
    "NHB" text,
    --"Purpose" varchar, 
    "value" double precision
);
```

When I run the script I get this error:

```
ERROR:  return and sql tuple descriptions are incompatible.
```

What am I doing wrong in the script?

Comment: Try removing `"Weight" double precision` from crosstab row definition.

Comment: It looks like your "HBW", "HBO", ... columns should be `NUMERIC`, not `TEXT`.

Comment: Igor and Daniel, I tried your solutions but the error remains !!!!. I have also edited the script to reflect proper field names.

Comment: It would be best to provide the table definition with data types - what you get with `\d tbl` in `psql`. Assuming `double precision` for your data columns. Adapt to your actual data type ...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This works for me on Postgres 9.3:

```
SELECT *
FROM   crosstab (
 $$SELECT id, class, "value"
   FROM   _tlfd
   WHERE  class = ANY ('{HBW, HBO, NHB}')
   ORDER  BY 1,2$$
   ) AS t (
        class int,                   -- needs a table alias!
        "HBW" float8,                -- resulting columns are double precision!
        "HBO" float8,
        "NHB" float8
        -- "value" double precision  -- column does not exist in result!
    );
```

Produces the desired output.

#### Essential changes

- the table alias (bold **`t`**)
- the removed surplus column `"value"`
- the correct data type for your data columns (`double precision` a.k.a. `float8`)

The rest is a matter of taste and style. I wouldn't use `value` as column name though, since it is a [reserved word in SQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-keywords-appendix.html).

Basics for `crosstab()` queries here:

- [PostgreSQL Crosstab Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002499/postgresql-crosstab-query/11751905#11751905)

Comment: This worked like a charm. Thank you. THe $$ before SELECT was something I could not find in the documentation.

Comment: @user3357558: Dollar-quoting is explained (plus link to documentation) in the link at the end of my answer.