# Using crosstab to convert rows to columns fails

Tags: sql, postgresql, crosstab

I have a postgres table with the following format:

```
id            key             value
-------------------------------------
a              1               p
b              2               q
c              3               r
a              2               s
```

I want to convert it into the following format:

```
id            1             2            3
--------------------------------------------
a             p             s
b                           q
c                                        r
```

I am trying to using the following crosstab() query to do this:

```
create extension tablefunc;

select * from crosstab(
'select id, key, value
from table
order by 1,2')
as ct(id text, key integer, value text);
```

However, it fails with the following exception:

```
ERROR:  return and sql tuple descriptions are incompatible
********** Error **********

ERROR: return and sql tuple descriptions are incompatible
SQL state: 42601
```

What am I missing here?

**Update:** There are around 25 keys in the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You **must** provide a second parameter with the list of possible values to allow for missing values in each resulting row:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   crosstab(
         'SELECT id, key, value
          FROM   tbl
          ORDER  BY 1, 2'
       , 'SELECT generate_series(1,25)'  -- assuming your key is type integer
       ) AS ct(id text
       , "1" text, "2" text, "3" text, "4" text, "5" text
       , "6" text, "7" text, "8" text, "9" text, "10" text
       , "11" text, "12" text, "13" text, "14" text, "15" text
       , "16" text, "17" text, "18" text, "19" text, "20" text
       , "21" text, "22" text, "23" text, "24" text, "25" text);
```

Detailed explanation:

- [PostgreSQL Crosstab Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002499/postgresql-crosstab-query/11751905#11751905)

If you get tired of typing the lengthy column definition list, consider this related (advanced) answer:

- [Dynamic alternative to pivot with CASE and GROUP BY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15506199/dynamic-alternative-to-pivot-with-case-and-group-by/15514334#15514334)

Comment: It returns empty rows for values when I add `'SELECT generate_series(1, 25)'`.

Comment: @i08in: Define "empty row". All columns NULL? If you can't resolve this, start by providing the exact table definition of `tbl` in your question.

Comment: No, only the entries in the columns "1", "2", "3", .... "25" are empty. key is integer.

Comment: @i08in: That's per design and happens for any `id` that shows up in your base table but without any matching `key` (number between 1 and 25 in the example).

Comment: Thanks! The problem was the sequence was not in order from 1-25. My bad. You got it solved :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM crosstab(
                'SELECT id, 
                        key, 
                        value
                   FROM table
               ORDER BY 1, 2'
               )
    AS CT(id text, one text, two text, three text);
```

You need the final four column names in `as ct()`, check [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/tablefunc.html) for more details

Comment: Other than having to explicitly add twenty-five column headers, this seems to be solution. Thanks :) BTW, what is the purpose of the 'order by' here?

Comment: @i08in: This solves the immediate cause for the error message, but it's not the solution. You have missing values per result rows in your example, which cannot be solved properly with the 1-parameter form of `crosstab()`. You need the 2-parameter form.

Answer (score 0):

Please reference with below code.
I hope it will work for you.

```
SELECT * 
  FROM crosstab(
                'SELECT id, 
                        key, 
                        "value"
                   FROM table                   
               ORDER BY  1,2'
               )
    AS t(id text, "1" text,"2" text, "3" text);
```

If you are not enough, you can also refer similar problem on this link.
[PostgreSQL says "return and sql tuple descriptions are incompatible"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22052334/postgresql-says-return-and-sql-tuple-descriptions-are-incompatible-what-doe)